# How to use correctly the same header file in different header files

Tags: c, header-files

I have some problems with header files in C.

I created a static library in C and have the following problem:

In a header file I've implemented a structure in (structure.h) and functions to operate it. So I have another header file (file1.h) using this structure. The problem starts because I have another file (file2.h) that need the same structure.h. Both (file1.h) and (file2.h) are independent of each other.

As (file1.h) uses the structure in (structure.h), if I try to use (structure.h) in (file2.h), I get errors in the file main.c.

How I can use correctly structure.h in different header files without getting errors?

Comment: The problem description isn't really clear, but try searching for `include guards`.

Comment: What is the error? Can you describe it or post the error message?

Comment: The error prompted by CodeLite is that file2.h attempts to redefine the content of structure.h. It's because structure.h is included twice (in file1.h and file2.h). 
I've got 9 error messages like this: 
error: redefinition of...

Answer (score 1):

It's a redefinition problem.
You should use:

```
  #ifndef NAME_H
  #define NAME_H

  //function declarations

  #endif
```

In every header file. 
These are called include guards.
More Info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Comment: No identifiers beginning with an underscore and a capital at global scope please.

Answer (score 1):

In general you should do 2 things:

1. wrap entire `structure.h` in `#ifndef` :

`#ifndef structure_h`

`#define structure_h`

`//structure.h content goes here`

`#endif // structure_h`

2. You should not implement functions in `.h` file. Implement them in `.c` file instead. `.h` is just for declaring them.

Comment: I know, i have the .h file and the corresponding .c file. I don't speak english very well, and same time it can lead to mistakes.

Comment: Note: Some compilers do not like extra text on `endif` as in `#endif // structure_h`.    Suggest putting comment on separate line.